# How should I fix my music library (Windows 7) which does everything but open when attempted?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, libraries

As I mentioned in the question above, it doesn't open. However, I can normally go to its properties to include/exclude folders. It's still functional, I believe. I just can't get INSIDE it. All the other libraries (e.g. documents, pictures) are just fine and accessible.

Comment: What happens when you try to open it? Do all the paths listed in the properties for that library actually still exist? Can you access them directly?

Comment: Nothing happens. The included folders are all fine and accessible.